# What is the best practise for loading extra JavaScript in the footer?

Tags: php, libraries

Every page of my website consist of:

- generic header
- the page itself
- generic footer

In code the page looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');
load_header('title', 'meta description'); // loads also MENU
?>

// Unique content of the page

<?php
// footer settings
$load_contact_info = true;

// load footer
require_once('footer.php');
load_footer($load_contact_info);
?>
```

On same pages I would like to load extra content (like more JS libraries) in the `footer.php` (right before  - closing body tag):

```
<?php
function load_footer($load_contact_info = false) {
?>
  <footer>
    <?php if ($load_contact_info) { ?>
    <div id="contact-us">
      // contact info
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="inner-footer">
      // more generic footer content
    </div>

  </footer>
  <script src="<?php echo($url); ?>js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

    // I want to load more UNIQUE JS content here at SOME pages

  </body>
  </html>
<?php } ?>
```

What is the best practise for loading extra libraries in the footer? Should I extend the `footer.php` with more if-yes-load-more like this:

```
if ($google_maps_api) {
  // map settings
  echo "<script src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap\" async defer></script>";
}
if ($other_api) {
  echo "<script src=\"https://example.com/other-api/\" async defer></script>";
}
```

Or are there any other possibilites to do it better?

Answer (score 2):

Load extra libraries should not be the task for a footer. A footer displays the footer. you should create a new php file and name it something like "handle_js.php"

```
function print_script_tag($src, $options) {
    echo "<script src=\"" . $src . "\" " . $options . "></script>\n";
}

function print_all_script_tags_for_url($url) {
  if($url === 'example') {
    print_script_tag('library.js','async');
  }
}
```

and in your footer file

```
</footer>
print_scripts($url);
</body>
```

I didn't test the code.

Comment: Ok and how would you handle the situations where there is - on some pages - also extra JS content besides loading the JS libraries (like Google Maps settings)? The only solution I came up with was including the extra content in the generic file (`footer.php` or `handle_js.php`) and if-load it every time it is needed. But that seems like wasting resources. It would be better to just somehow save that content to the variable in the unique page itself and then execute it at the end of file at `footer.php` (or `handle_js.php`).

Comment: you put the extra js content in a script file at load than do print_scripts("js_extra_content.js") at the end.